# Faster mouse acceleration on XFCE4

Tags: mouse

Is there any way to make mouse moves faster? I'm using 4K display, and 10x acceleration still too slow.

[image: 10x acceleration]

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom acceleration value using xset. For example to set it to 15, in commandline, run:

```
xset m 15 1
```